# Raycast is only working when I move at a moderate speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I used to raycast to destroy things in my game and it didn't work unless I moved quite fast I attached this script to my main camera in unity, Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong as I want it to happen regardless of movement whether you're still or not.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos, Vector2.zero, 100f);
            
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Ground")
            {
                Debug.Log("You clicked a block and tried to break it!");
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you getting errors? You assume the hit object is always populated, you should check if not null first.

Answer (score 0):

Physics2D.Raycast should be used in FixedUpdate because in there is when the physics are calculate. Physics are not frame dependant.

Comment: I tried doing this but it just gives me the same issue, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html):

`RaycastHit2D Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, float distance)`

You've given the raycast a **zero** direction.

Generally, you should use `ScreenPointToRay` and pass the ray origin and direction to Raycast instead